# $.post() in jQuery not working as expected

Tags: jquery

```
$('a').click(function(event){
            $('body').html('loading...');
            $.post('www.sitename.com/hello',{site:"http//:www.google.com"},function(data) {
                    alert(data);
             });
             event.preventDefault();


     });
```

I am using the above script to override the default behavior of the links .The site referred here returns the HTML of the 'site' parameter.but the page just stops after printing loading...

Comment: That's not a POST, that's a GET...

Comment: Yes, that is what the code does. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @Mef: Am I missing something? What makes it a GET?

Comment: @Matt: I missed that he actually sends data along with the request... So using POST is actually fine. My bad =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks fine. Do you try to access a foreign domain?
Ajax Cross domain policy would not allow that.

Comment: yeah thats why i switched to IE

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to debug your code, by adding an error handler (the error could be on your `hello` handler, a JavaScript access denied exception, etc):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/hello",
    dataType:"html",
    data:{site:"http//:www.google.com"},
    success:function(data){
       alert(data);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       alert(xhr.statusText);
    }    
});
```

Also, make sure the url is **http://**, not **http//:** , and check the error console for other JavaScript errors - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Firefox.

Comment: yeah that was really helpful also ctr+shift+j was a huge addition to my knowledge .

Comment: i used html.body(data); but seems that would just inset the text of the page into the body and not the images etc.Is there a way data can be used to get the whole page (images+data+css and whatever the page may contain.)

Comment: Not really. The images and files fail because they have the wrong relative url... You can fix most of these using the `<base>` tag, but some will get away. You still have a problem with outgoing links, or dead relative links (again, `<base>` can help partially). Be careful, the work can get difficult - I know a program that rewrites your JS to avoid uncontrolled redirect! (it even changes `eval` statements)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your $.post() with:

```
$('body').load('www.google.com');
```

EDIT: this won't work because the whole dom of Google's page (including the header) will be inserted into the .